# How to create different relationships with same entity in Neo4J/Spring?

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using Spring Data Neo4J with Spring Boot v1.3.1. My Neo4J version is 2.1.6 .
Let's say, I have an Entity Person, which can have a relation named `Friend` with a Set of Person. So, I define a `Set` as one of the attributes of the Entity, use the `@RelatedTo` annotation and give it a type named `Friend`.

What if I want to have multiple other relationships, all with the same entity only, let's say, `Enemy`, `Acquaintance` etc. Do I have to define, separate attributes for all of them ? Can't I pass the relationship dynamically ?

For reference:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person {

@RelatedTo(type="FRIEND", direction=Direction.BOTH)
public @Fetch Set<Person> friends;

//Do I have to do it like this ? This is odd.
@RelatedTo(type="ENEMY", direction=Direction.BOTH)
public @Fetch Set<Person> enemies;

//getter setters

}
```

**EDIT 1-----------**

Right now, I'm facing an issue with creating nodes in a bulk. Explaining the problem below : 
After considering the approach suggested by Michael, here is what I have.
Basically, I have to create a lot of nodes in bulk. This node, `Person` will have an attribute with a unique index over it. Let's call it `name`. So, when the relations, `Friend` or `Enemy` are created, I want them to be created with person with unique name.
So, there will be two steps:

1. Create the Person nodes.(takes lot of time)
2. Create the relations between them.(does not take much time, around 30-40 ms)

I tried different approaches of creating nodes in bulk.

One approach was to commit the transactions after a certain number of nodes have been saved.
I had followed this [link](http://iordanis.com/post/22677357894/import-large-graphs-to-neo4j-with-spring-data-fast)
I'm not sure about the performance improvement as calling the `neo4jTemplate.save()` still takes around 500ms.

From my logs:

```
Time taken to execute save:=612 ms
Time taken to execute save:=566 ms
```

Is this supposed to alright ?

Another approach was using Cypher, as suggested by Michael in his blog, [here.](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/03/quickly-create-a-100k-neo4j-graph-data-model-with-cypher-only/)

I used a Cypher query like this :

```
WITH [{name: "Person1", gravity: 1}, 
      {name: "Person2", gravity: 2}] AS group
FOREACH (person IN group | 
CREATE (e:Person {label: person.name, gravity: person.gravity}))
```

Issue with this approach is nodes do get created in bulk, but the unique index on name attribute is ignored. It seems, I must commit after saving each node.

So, is there any other way, in which I will be able to create nodes in bulk in a faster manner ?

Answer (score 1):

You can handle it with creating relationship entities of the different types.

Or using `Neo4jTemplate` directly (`createRelationshipBetween`).

If you have such a dynamic setup, what would your entities look like?

You don't have to list the relationships in your entity. If they are dynamic you can also just have base attributes in your entities and access the relationships via a repository.

Comment: I have updated my question with my latest findings. The approach suggested by you does solve the problem, but node creation takes a long time. Can you please take a look and let me know, if it is alright for neo4j to take that much time to a create a node, or suggest any other way ?